# Is it right to ceate actor instance for each new process managed by FMS

Tags: akka.net

I'm trying to design application which will manage multi state processes. Something like money transfer processes from one account to another. I have decided to use Akka.Net FMS. But then I have stucked when I found out that each new process (new Transfer) needs new actor instance because FMS state is stored in "running" actor. For me it means that if I have 1000 simultaneous requests for transfer then I should create 1000 instances. Keeping in mind that according the documentation each actor is working in its own thread how realistic is this approach?. Or did I understand anything wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actors don't work "in their own threads", they work on one thread at a time which is different thing - you can have millions of actors working perfectly on 2 OS threads, but at any given time the same actor will always be executed only one one of them (*unless you'll escape that barrier explicitly eg. by running task inside of an actor*). Single actor by itself occupies less than 1kB or memory and doesn't have any inherent requirements on operating system resources (like threads).

In general having one actor working as a transfer coordinator is ok and it's quite common pattern in Akka.NET.